# Analogue of splitting field in several variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $k$ be a field, and $P \in k[X]$. Consider the extensions
$k \subset L \subset K$, where $L$ is a splitting field for $P$ over $k$ and $K$ is the algebraic closure of $k$.
Then (by definition) all roots of $P$ in $K$ actually belong to the smaller field $L$.

What happens to that picture in several variables ? More precisely, let $P_1, \ldots, P_n \in k[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$. Consider the subset
$$Z=\bigcap_i P_i^{-1}(0) \subset K^n.$$

Generically $Z$ is finite. Question : is there an analogue of the splitting field, i.e. a smallest extension $k \subset L$ such that $Z \subset L^n$ ?

I realize this is probably very classical, so please forgive my ignorance. 
I would be glad to just have a precise reference for this question.

EDIT

I wrote the question for $k^n$ but it might be more relevant for $\mathbb P^n(k)$.

EDIT 2

Thanks to an answer, I realize that as such my question was not properly formulated, because there is a always a smallest field $L$ containing any subset $Z$. What I am interested in is the relationship between $L$ and the $P_i$. 
Also, are the components of points in $Z$ algebraic over $k$ ? (I would say yes, but I don't know how to prove it). If so, is there a natural construction of a polynomial $Q \in k[X]$ in terms of the $P_i$ annihilating, say, the first component of a given $z \in Z$ ?

Comment: The claim that generically $Z$ is finite is a little ambiguous for me. Do you mean that generically $Z$ is a finite set? If so then this is not true. For example, the locus of points (what you wrote to be $Z$), for the curve $W^2=Z^3-Z+1$ considered in $\mathbb{C}[W,Z]$ has an "infinite locus". To see this, fix any $W=w_0\in \mathbb{C}$ and by the fundamental theorem of algebra there must be $3$ roots of the polynomial. In this way we can vary $W$ and get an infinite set.

Comment: @Eoin OK, but the locus of that curve is the zero set of only one polynomial map $P = W^2 - Z^3 -Z+1$. If you pick a generic pair of curves, won't their intersection be finite ?

Comment: I think you are right. Isn't there something like Bezout's theorem which says this? I wasn't considering that the intersection must include $n$ polynomials. Hopefully someone gives an answer!

Comment: @Eoin yes, in fact that is Bézout's theorem. I asked for the intersection in the case of $n$ polynomials which is most relevant for my situation, but my question makes sense even if there is fewer polynomials considered

Answer (score 0):

I think the polynomials are a bit of a red herring here. Given any subset $Z\subset K^n$, finite or not, define
  $$L = \bigcap \{M\mid K/M/k\text{ and }Z\subset M^n\}.$$
This will satisfy your "analogue of splitting field" property by definition. Another way to obtain $L$ is as the subextension of $K/k$ generated over $k$ by the coordinates of the elements of $Z$. Thus, if $Z$ is finite, then $L/k$ is a finite extension.

Comment: right. I guess what I'm really asking is whether we can characterize $Z$ in terms of the $P_i$. For instance, are the coordinates of $Z$ algebraic over $k$ ?

Comment: @Hal by definition, the coordinates of elements of $Z$ are algebraic over $k$, as you've defined $Z$ to be a subset of $K^n$ for an algebraic closure $K/k$. What is the question you really want to ask here?

Comment: according to the definition of algebraic I have in mind, it's that you can write it as the root of polynomial $P \in k[X]$. is it obvious that you can find such a $P$ is in this setting for each coordinate and each point in $Z$ ?

Comment: @Hal It is not the case that every root in every extension of $k$ of a multivariable polynomial has coordinates which are algebraic over $k$. Consider the trivial example $P(x, y) = x - y\in k[x, y]$. Then $(\pi, \pi)$ is a root of $P$ for every element $\pi$ of every extension of $k$, algebraic or not. In your question you defined $Z$ to be a subset of $K^n$ so per your definition the points in $Z$ have coordinates algebraic over $k$.